# utility class in to serve different TabItems

Tags: c#, class, utility

I'm new to C# and I'm trying to find out whats the way to write a utility class that could serve, in my case, a few different tabitems. In JAVA I could write an Enum class for that purpose. How do you do that in C#?

Comment: Can you explain better what you need or what you're trying to do? Thanks...

Comment: you can write a class and add utility function into ... if you are not more specific I won't be either. Enum are made to enumerate a set of named constants, they don't do anything.

Comment: I want to build a class that will provide access to methods for a few different classes. All the class will need access to the same instance of this "utility" class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to tell what exactly the question is, but if you are looking to declare an enumeration, C# has the `enum` keyword (see: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)).  E.g.:

```
enum Days {Sat, Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri};
```

You can then use the `enum` directly:

```
public void PrintDayName(Days day)
{
   //...
}
```

Regarding your comment:

> I want to build a class that will provide access to methods for a few different classes. All the class will need access to the same instance of this "utility" class.

If you refer to the enum as above, it will effectively be the "same instance", since each enum value simply represents some integral value (e.g. 0, 1, 2, 3, etc).  If you are referring to an actual utility class, those are typically implemented as `static` classes, which works pretty similarly to how Java treats the `static` keyword.